# Generated Gradle build files from Eclipse, getting error: Gradle version 1.10 is required

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

I generated a Gradle build file from an Eclipse project, then ran `gradle build` in the source root dir, which generated the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/me/src/myproject/build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':src:myproject'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/me/src/myproject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

This is the auto-generated `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':tools:android-sdk-linux_86:extras:android:support:v7:appcompat')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

On the other hand, [this project](https://github.com/mvglasow/satstat/blob/ea3ce8f2ca5c8f120ba891c84865b50f3a5ab3b7/build.gradle) builds without any issues.

I’ve tried copying the `buildscript` block as well as any missing sub-blocks of `android` over, as well as commenting out the top-level `dependencies` block, to no avail.

If it matters, OS is Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit), gradle 2.10.

What gives?

Comment: Why don't you use the android studio IDE?

Comment: Android Studio won’t build my desktop application written in C (which Eclipse does, thanks to CDT), making AS just another step towards more fragmentation. Therefore I’m looking for a way that allows me to keep Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to build using Gradle Wrapper.

Since `gradle wrapper` would also fail with the same error message (have 2.10, want 1.10), I just copied over `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat` and the `gradle` subdir from another project that I’ve previously built successfully.

`gradlew build` would still complain about the version, so I edited the version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` as directed by the error message.

Then some modifications to `build.gradle` (not all of them may be necessary):

Add a new block at the top:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}
```

This will, among others, specify JCenter as a repository for dependencies. For Maven Central specify `mavenCentral()` instead of `jcenter()`, which will work as well.

Modify the `dependencies` block: Since we’re pulling the Android support libraries in from a repository, disable local builds. Delete the following line:

```
compile project(':tools:android-sdk-linux_86:extras:android:support:v7:appcompat')
```

If you don’t have any local jars to include, drop the other line as well (in which case you can eliminate the entire section). I had one single jar to include (besides appcompat), so I kept the line and changed `*.jar` to the name of the jar I needed. (Alternatively, delete duplicate jars from your libs dir, but that will break ant builds directly from Eclipse.)

In the `android` block, add the following children:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.+'
}
```

API versions in `defaultConfig` should match those in your app manifest.

`lintOptions` is important if your project contains some non-critical issues (unused declarations, use of deprecated APIs and the like), else these will cause build to fail.

`dependencies` may vary depending on the libraries you’re including via JCenter. I noticed appcompat-v7 v23.2 and higher would give me compile errors (which is likely a separate issue), so I stuck with the last ones that worked.

With all of these, the project finally builds. So much about Google maintaining backward compatibility...